# React isn't setting the state as i expect

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, react-hooks, axios

I have two pieces of code, the Front-end in React and the Bakc-end in Laravel, the problem is im calling the API to get an array of a SQL join but in the useEffect React Hook it doest get the info, but if i make a button to get it works, i don't know why the useEffect Hook isn't working properly

**I partially solved the question by treating the response as an array but if you are sending more than 1 thing i still dont know what to do**

I have this pieces of code

**Laravel:**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $returned = response('El lote solicitado no existe', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

        $lote = DB::table('lotes')
        ->leftjoin('articulos', 'lotes.idArticulo', '=', 'articulos.id')
        ->select('lotes.idLote', 'lotes.idArticulo', 'lotes.cantidad', 'lotes.consumoPreferente', 'lotes.observaciones', 'articulos.descripcion')
        ->where('lotes.id', $id)
        ->get();

        if($lote){
            $returned = response($lote, Response::HTTP_OK);
        }

        return $returned;
    }
```

**React:**

```
const [lote, setLote] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = `Lote ${id}`
        getLote()
    }, [])

    const { id } = useParams()

    const getLote = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${endpoint}/lote/${id}`)
            setLote(response.data)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Error ${e}`)
        }

    }
```

The problem is that lote isn't setting in the useEffect hook, but if i call the getLote function outside of it works.

Another issue is that if i change the laravel part to this works properly on the useEffect call:

I think the key is here, if i use the 'findOrFail' it works properly but if make a SQL query it doesn't, but if im using the async - await it should wait, rigth?

```
$lote = Lote::findOrFail($id);
        if($lote ){
            $returned = response($lote , Response::HTTP_OK);
        }

        return $returned;
```

Also to mention im ussing axios to make the calls, could it be the problem too?

Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: You only need to trigger the useEffect when the component is mounted?

Comment: Check once if you are getting `id` in the `getLote()`. See if in the first render it's `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, i only need the useEffect once when the component is mounted and the 'id' is comming from the father so it comes as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to make sure that **id** is already defined in `useEffect`, so you need to re-write `useEffect` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!id) {
    return;
  }
  document.title = `Lote ${id}`
  getLote()
}, [id]);
```

also, I would recommend putting function in `useCallback`

```
const getLote = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${endpoint}/lote/${id}`)
            setLote(response.data)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Error ${e}`)
        }

    }, [id]);
```

It is crucial to add relevant dependencies in deps array.

Comment: It keeps not working, i think the problem could be on laravel not giving the data fast enough (maybe that's a stupid statement), or the useEffect isn't working well because it works if i run the last section of code but i doesn't if i run the first one

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question by doing an intermediate step

**If the data that is being sended is only one object in the array**

```
const [lote, setLote] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = `Lote ${id}`
        getLote()
    }, [])

    const { id } = useParams()

    const getLote = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${endpoint}/lote/${id}`)
            setLote(response.data[0])
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Error ${e}`)
        }

    }
```

**If the data that is being sended are more than one object in the array**

```
const [lote, setLote] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = `Lote ${id}`
        getLote()
    }, [])

    const { id } = useParams()

    const getLote = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${endpoint}/lote/${id}`)
            let newLote = response.data
            setLote(newLote)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Error ${e}`)
        }

    }
```

**I don't know why this happens but this solution worked for me**